# how to create a quiz using HTML5

Tags: html

I know this is slightly broad question but I'm looking to build a quiz similar to http://net.tutsplus.com/articles/quizzes/nettuts-quiz-6-how-well-do-you-know-html5/ but also with with drag and drop capabilities but unsure of where to start looking.
Any ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can investigate the `tutsplus` quiz using Developer Tools in Google Chrome or FireBug in Firefox.

Some idea on how it is done :

Taking number of questions as : 10.

- Quiz contains different slides.
- So we have

  - Welcome slide
  - 10 slides (one slide for each question)
  - Results slide
- Each question slide will have

  - a Question
  - four Options
  - Next button
- We will show only one slide at any time.
- On start - We will show only the first Welcome slide and hide all other slides.
- Whenever we click on Start (Welcome Slide) or Next (Questions slide) or Finish (Last slide), it will just hide the current slide and show the next slide.
- Whenever we click on any answer, we will add a class to it.
- In the Results slide, we check these selected items against the answers and calculate the result.
- Before-hand we need all the questions, options and their correct answers.

This is how `tutsplus` quiz is implemented using

- HTML
- CSS
- JavaScript/jQuery

Regarding the Drag and Drop, we can use jQuery UI Draggable, jQuery UI Droppable and Sortable depending upon your requirement.

You can use many other ways to implement what you need and also some back-end technologies for more questions and sets.